# Search model with firm decision

Tags: search-and-matching

I am wondering if there is any work in search models that discusses firm behaviors. Most common search models that I am familiar with talk about the job seeker's threshold rule. Is there any model that discusses similar firm threshold rule, in investment in capital, effort etc.

Answer (score 2):

**The Neo-Schumpeterian literature** models firm behavior with "an search and select" approach. Nelson and Winter (2009) where the pioneers in the subject, it is a pleasant and interesting reading.

[Nelson, Richard R.; Winter, Sidney G. An evolutionary theory of economic change. Harvard University Press, 2009](http://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674272286)